# Numpy apply function to every item in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So let's say I have a 2d array. How can I apply a function to every single item in the array and replace that item with the return? Also, the function's return will be a tuple, so the array will become 3d.

Here is the code in mind.

```py
def filter_func(item):
    if 0 <= item < 1:
        return (1, 0, 1)
    elif 1 <= item < 2:
        return (2, 1, 1)
    elif 2 <= item < 3:
        return (5, 1, 4)
    else:
        return (4, 4, 4)

myarray = np.array([[2.5, 1.3], [0.4, -1.0]])

# Apply the function to an array

print(myarray)

# Should be array([[[5, 1, 4],
#                   [2, 1, 1]],
#                  [[1, 0, 1],
#                   [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Any ideas how I could do it? One way is to do `np.array(list(map(filter_func, myarray.reshape((12,))))).reshape((2, 2, 3))` but that's quite slow, especially when I need to do it on an array of shape (1024, 1024).

I've also seen people use np.vectorize, but it somehow ends up as `(array([[5, 2], [1, 4]]), array([[1, 1], [0, 4]]), array([[4, 1], [1, 4]])).` Then it has shape of (3, 2, 2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to change anything in your function.

Just apply the vectorized version of your function to your array
and *stack* the result:

```
np.stack(np.vectorize(filter_func)(myarray), axis=2)
```

The result is:

```
array([[[5, 1, 4],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Comment: This parameter specifies, along which axis the stacking is to occur (described in *Numpy* documentation). Try my code with axis == *1* and *0* to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed. It's about 8 times faster than my first try!

Comment: In my timings this `vectorize` is slower than your `list(map...)`.  I've always found `vectorize` to be slower than plain iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Your list-map:

```
In [4]: np.array(list(map(filter_func, myarray.reshape((4,))))).reshape((2, 2, 3))                   
Out[4]: 
array([[[5, 1, 4],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

A variation using nested list comprehension:

```
In [5]: np.array([[filter_func(j) for j in row] for row in myarray])                                 
Out[5]: 
array([[[5, 1, 4],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Using `vectorize`, the result is one array for each element returned by the function.

```
In [6]: np.vectorize(filter_func)(myarray)                                                           
Out[6]: 
(array([[5, 2],
        [1, 4]]),
 array([[1, 1],
        [0, 4]]),
 array([[4, 1],
        [1, 4]]))
```

As @Vladi shows these can be combined with `stack` (or `np.array` followed by a transpose):

```
In [7]: np.stack(np.vectorize(filter_func)(myarray),2)                                               
Out[7]: 
array([[[5, 1, 4],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Your list-map is fastest.  I've never found `vectorize` to be faster:

```
In [8]: timeit np.array(list(map(filter_func, myarray.reshape((4,))))).reshape((2, 2, 3))            
17.2 µs ± 47.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [9]: timeit np.array([[filter_func(j) for j in row] for row in myarray])                          
20.5 µs ± 78.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [10]: timeit np.stack(np.vectorize(filter_func)(myarray),2)                                       
75.2 µs ± 297 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Taking the `np.vectorize(filter_func)` out of the timing loop helps just a bit.

`frompyfunc` is similar to `vectorize`, but returns object dtype.  It usually is faster:

```
In [29]: timeit np.stack(np.frompyfunc(filter_func, 1,3)(myarray),2).astype(int)                     
28.7 µs ± 125 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Generally if you have a function that only takes scalar inputs, it's hard to do better than simple iteration.  `vectorize/frompyfunc` don't improve on that.  Optimal use of `numpy` requires rewriting the function to work directly with arrays, as @Hammad demonstrates.

Though with this small example, even this proper `numpy` solution isn't faster.  I expect it will scale better:

```
In [32]: timeit func(myarray)                                                                        
25 µs ± 60.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: The list map took 6.34 seconds on a 1024 by 1024 array, but the vectorize only took 1.18 seconds. Mabye the list-map is better for smaller arrays.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this function, with vectorised implementation

```
def func(arr):
    
    elements = np.array([
        [1, 0, 1],
        [2, 1, 1],
        [5, 1, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
    ])
    
    arr  = arr.astype(int)
    mask = (arr != 0) & (arr != 1) & (arr != 2)

    arr[mask] = -1
    
    return elements[arr]
```

you wont be able to rewrite your array because of shape mismatch
but you could overwrite the variable `myarray`

```
myarray = func(myarray)
myarray

>>>   [[[5, 1, 4],
        [2, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 1],
        [4, 4, 4]]]
```

Comment: Umm how would I do it if I had a function already? I don't really understand what your code does