# NumPy: Sum over 1-D array split by index

Tags: python, numpy, split, sum, vectorization

Consider a 1-D *NumPy* input array and a sorted index array. The goal is to get the sum over the input array, `a`, but split by the indices defined in the index array.

Below are two approaches, but both of them require slow Python for loops. Is there a pure *NumPy* version without the need of Python for loops?

**Example**:

```py
a = np.arange(20) # Input array
idxs = np.array([7, 15, 16]) # Index array

# Goal: Split a at index 7, 15 and 16 and
# compute sum for each partition

# Solution 1:
idxs_ext = np.concatenate(([0], idxs, [a.size]))
results = np.empty(idxs.size + 1)
for i in range(results.size):
    results[i] = a[idxs_ext[i]:idxs_ext[i+1]].sum()

# Solution 2:
result = np.array(
    [a_.sum() for a_ in np.split(a, idxs)]
)

# Result: array([21., 84., 15., 70.])
```

Comment: check out `add.reduceat`

Comment: would it be ok to use numba?

Comment: Of course, Numba is totally fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you can split the `a` array based on your `idxs` array by `np.split` and then apply your function on that as:

```
np.stack(np.vectorize(np.sum)(np.array(np.split(a, idxs), dtype=object)))
```

Another answer is using `np.add.reduceat` as it is mentioned by @hpaulj in the comments and is more faster:

```
np.add.reduceat(a, np.insert(idxs, 0, 0), axis=0)
```

***Update:***
Using `np.concatenate` instead of `insert` reduced the runtime 5 times for data range 1000 with 7 slices; ***It was the fastest method I have examined:***

```
np.add.reduceat(a, np.concatenate(([0], idxs)), axis=0)
```

Comment: You iterate over the splitted arrays in Python. The only difference to my example is that you use `map` instead of ist comprehension, which is, as far as I know, not faster for single process applications.

Comment: @Yannic Now it is pure numpy. In large data, numba and … could make your python loops very efficient. See [this useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864282/numpy-apply-function-to-every-item-in-array) on SO.

Comment: I have answered your question as you asked for pure NumPy. But in terms of speed, as it is mentioned in the link in my last comment, loops may be faster in some codes. I have tested your code and mine on the google colab TPU, your first solution is the fastest among them by using just `@nb.jit()`; which revealed 5 times faster comparing without numba on this small sample case: `100 loops, best of 5: 5.5 µs per loop`.

Comment: Adding the `reduce.at` saves your answer (in my eyes).  Though I'd use the OP's  `idxs_ext[:-1]` instead of the `insert`.  `np.vectorize` is nearly always slower than a list comprehension.  It's worth noting that `np.split` is itself a python level iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, you are right. In terms of speed, `np.add.reduceat` is the correct answer. It did not seem that you want to write the answer, and just a hint in the comment. I apologize if I used it quickly in my answer (although I mentioned you). I have checked the speed with `np.concatenate(([0], idxs))` instead `np.insert(idxs, 0, 0)`, for a data range 1000 and 7 slices, and it was about 5 times faster than `insert` (`4.7 µs per loop`). I did not know such a thing until now about `np.split`. Thank you for this valuable point. I will be appreciated if you reference me to read more about it.